# Fastest way to convert float to bytes and then save byte array in memory?

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte, primitive-types

I am currently writing code that converts an audio clip into a float array and then want to convert that float array into bytes, and finally convert that byte array to hexadecimal.

Everything works but we are attempting to save arrays of data that are hundreds of thousands of elements long when this data is converted to bytes and once we try to save this data as a hexadecimal string it is a bit much or takes too  long for the mobile devices we are testing on to handle.

So my question is are there any ways to optimize / speed up this process?

**Here is my code for Convert our float array to bytes:**

```
public byte[]  ConvertFloatsToBytes(float[] audioData){

    byte[] bytes = new byte[audioData.Length * 4];

        //*** This function converts our current float array elements  to the same exact place in byte data 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(audioData,0,bytes,0,bytes.Length);



    return bytes;
}
```

**Here we convert that data into a hex string :**

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);

        //Debug.Log("ba.length = " + ba.Length.ToString() +"hex string = " + hex);
        return hex.Replace("-","");
    }
```

Ultimately at the end we save the string out and  convert it from the hex string to a float array .

Like I said that code is slow but it is working I am just trying to find the best ways to optimize / speed up this process to improve performance

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to keep all the data in memory? Can you work against streams instead?

Comment: Well it's basically saving an audio clip so that any time a player plays back the recording we can  recreate an audio clip with the data .  I actually haven't worked with emory streams yet though would they hold an advantage if I need to access the data in  memory stream at any time ?

Comment: I think `MemoryStream` uses an array as its backing store, so it wouldn't provide a performance benefit as far as I know. However, the Stream pattern (see System.IO.Stream) in general allows you to avoid holding the entire content in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know which part is costing you? I strongly suspect that the conversion to a hexadecimal array isn't the bottleneck in your program.

The final part, where you remove the hyphens ends up copying the string. You can probably do better by writing your own method that duplicates what `BitArray.ToString` does, without the hyphens. That is:

```
const string chars = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(ba.Length*2);
    for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; ++i)
    {
        var b = ba[i];
        sb.Append(chars[b >> 4]);
        sb.Append(chars[b & 0x0F]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

That will avoid one string copy.

If you're willing to use unsafe code (don't know if you can on the devices you're working with), you can speed that even further by not even copying to the array of bytes. Rather, you fix the array of floats in memory and then address it with a byte pointer See [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx) if you're interested in that.

Comment: You very well may be correct, but when i've commented out the audio saving portion of my code everything seems to work much more quickly .  I assumed because of the amount of data ( the audio files are typically between 1 and 3 MB's )   converting this much data was causing issues but maybe I should investigate further . also thanks for the tip on changing my conversion of the byte data to hex

Comment: @user3242608: How are you saving the data? That is, are you writing it to a file after doing the conversion?

Comment: At the end we save the data using a built in structure that saves persistent data . we save this string in memory .and then grab it whenever we load the data and convert the hex string back to a float array .

Comment: @user3242608: Then why are you converting it to hex? Can't you just save the float array directly? Or convert it to a `byte[]` and call [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I believe it's because ultimately we want to be able to send this data over a network and retrieve it on the other side but you may be correct, if I just write the byte array into memory there shouldn't be a reason I can't retrieve it , i'll look into doing that next.

Comment: I actually think this may be the solution in a way . instead of savign the bytes ( which was causing crashes) I saved the hex data string this way and was able to complete the saving of the audio and load it back correctly!

Comment: I think you were Correct Jim , it wasn't the actual saving or data conversion that crashed the app I think it was trying to put the populated ( and huge) text string into our save structure that ended up causing our app to crash . I don't know how much faster I can make saving occur but this solution prevented the crashes  at the very least which is a huge improvement , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

That sounds really convoluted - are audio samples not normally integers?

Anyway, StreamWriter supports writing of single and double natively, so you could use that to build a memory stream that you then convert to hex.

Comment: I am making a project using unity and the native function they offer to get the audio clip data returns a float array so I assume that's the only way to do it  or all i've found so far